# Does the elephant get bigger when I bring in the ballista?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Fairgrounds Trumpeter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFairgrounds%20Trumpeter%5d):

> At the beginning of each end step, if a +1/+1 counter was placed on a permanent under your control this turn, put a +1/+1 counter on Fairgrounds Trumpeter.

[Walking Ballista](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWalking%20Ballista%5d):

> Walking Ballista enters the battlefield with X +1/+1 counters on it.

If I bring in a new Walking Ballista - then it enters the game with the +1/+1 counters already on it. Technically you could interpret that as meaning that the +1/+1 counters were not placed on it that turn - they were already there as it entered the battlefield.

So does the trumpeter trumpet louder and the crowd cheer more when they see the ballista walk onto the field?

(Obviously if a new counter is added after the Ballista is on the field then it would, this is specifically about the replacement ability on entering the battlefield).

Comment: "Does the elephant get bigger when I bring in the ballista?" - this title would look nice at r/nocontext

Comment: I have an amusing image in my head of somebody holding their card horizontally in the air, balancing a die on it and then carefully lowering it to the table, so as to ensure that it literally *enters the battlefield with counters*. Future "Un-" expansion material, maybe.

Comment: @tsuma534 My alternative working title was "Does the elephant grow when the ballista walks in?"

Comment: Does Panharmonicon also triggers on undying or when Walking Ballista come into play?

Comment: @sinsedrix Panharmonicon would not trigger since this isn't an "enter the battlefield" trigger, it enters with the counters already on.

Comment: @TimB Why Fairgrounds Trumpeter would trigger and not Panharmonicon? The approved answer says it should be considered the same to place a counter or have them already placed on it.

Comment: @sinsedrix Panharmonicon looks for triggered abilities, which Ballista does not have. Fairgrounds Trumpeter looks for counters being placed, which Ballista does have.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you get the counter on Trumpeter.

When an ability is looking out for counters being placed on an object, the game also counts cards that enter the battlefield with counters as having had those "placed" on it: it will trigger abilities like Trumpeter's, [Hardened Scales](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHardened%20Scales%5d) would give the Ballista another +1/+1 counter, etc.

> **121.6**. Some spells and abilities refer to counters being “placed” on an object. This refers to putting counters on that object while it’s on the battlefield and also to an object that’s given counters as it enters the battlefield.

Comment: Would 
Winding Constrictor work and would it cumulate with Hardened Scales effect?